# build abseil on windows using bazel

Tags: bazel, abseil

im trying to build abseil on windows using bazel,

the version im trying to build is :

```
abseil-cpp-20181200
```

im using the next bazel command:

```
bazel build
```

im getting this output:

```
INFO: Invocation ID: d85f94c1-e562-4ede-9bcd-9ab7e39020f3
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Analyzing: 0 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
INFO: Analysed 0 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 0 targets...
[0 / 1] [-----] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.261s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

I see that some folders were created in abseil-cpp-20181200

```
bazel-abseil-cpp-20181200
bazel-bin
bazel-genfiles
bazel-out
bazel-testlogs
```

these folders are empty.

the system im using is windows7 64 bit

if more info is needed please tell me and I will supply it,
help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`bazel build` itself doesn't build anything. You'll have to specify a target to tell Bazel what to build. For example, if you want to build `strings`, specify the target `//absl/strings:strings`, or `//absl/strings` for short:

```
$ bazel build //absl/strings
```

See the [C++ Quickstart](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/quickstart) for more information.